# sed - pattern only on some predefined lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to use `sed` to give me some lines from a file. I want to extract these lines only within some part of the file, which I know. E.g. I have a file with 100 lines, and I am seeking for lines withing line 10 and 30 with a specific pattern.

My current solution is to use two `sed` commands: The first prints every thing between the line numbers I have, e.g.

```
sed -n "10,30p" target_file.file
```

The second searches withing that result with a pattern

```
sed -n '/pattern/p'
```

So in the end I have this:

```
sed -n "10,30p" target_file.file | sed -n '/pattern/p'
```

Is there a way, to make one command out of two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

```
$ sed -n '10,30{
  /pattern/p
}' <file
```

That's standard syntax for now. You can also use:

```
$ sed -n '10,30{/pattern/p;}' <file
```

in next POSIX version.